# Writing string to a .mc file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to write data to a file and it's not appearing but I know the program is finishing. I establish a writable file getting the name from a command argument

```
  FILE *outFilePtr;
```

Then I create the file through:

```
outFilePtr=fopen(outFileString,"w"); //outFileString is the name of the file from command
```

Now I attempt to print to this file which has a .mc extension:

```
fprintf(outFilePtr,"%s\n","1001") //example string
```

The file gets created and nothing is written to it.  This is probably a dumb question but can you not write strings to machine code files? I'm trying to find a solution to this problem if that's the case.

Comment: call `fclose(outfile);`  at the end

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "machine code file", here, but what you're actually going to end up with is a regular text file with the string "1001" in it.

Comment: If the program doesn't crash, the standard I/O buffers should be flushed and the file closed automatically (though I completely agree that the `fclose(outFilePtr);` would be better).  If the program crashes, then an empty file is all too plausible. There is nothing special about the extension `.mc` as far as a C program is concerned.

Comment: I figured this problem out but while I'm here i have a quick gdb question. I'm trying to run it with arguments and if argc!=3 it exits. Well gdb won't work when i go run > assembly (name of executable) testcase.as output.mc but it works when i omit assembly and exits out due to the error checking. Sorry for the randomness just trying to solve this related bug

Answer (score 0):

You should check the results of fopen and fprintf.  This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *outFilePtr;

  outFilePtr = fopen("asdf.mc", "w");
  if(!outFilePtr) {
    perror("Couldn't open it");
    fprintf(stderr, "errno:  %d\n", errno);
    exit(-1);
  }
  if(fprintf(outFilePtr, "%s\n", "1001") < 0)
  {
    fclose(outFilePtr);
    perror("Couldn't write to it");
    fprintf(stderr, "errno:  %d\n", errno);
    exit(-1);
  }
  fclose(outFilePtr);
}
```

If there is a problem opening the file (permissions, etc), perror will show it.  For example, using an empty string for the filename gave me this in a window$ machine:

```
Couldn't open it: Invalid argument
errno:  22
```

If I close outFilePtr before the fprintf, this error gets displayed:

```
Couldn't write to it: Bad file descriptor
errno:  9
```

Answer (score 0):

please check that you close the file(using fclose(fptr)) after fprintf()..